# ImageMagick Installation via SSH Error "./configure.lineno: line 480: expr: command not found"

Tags: ssh, imagemagick

I simply want to install ImageMagick on my Webserver. I've tried it yesterday on a testserver and everything worked fine. Today on the production server I get an error 
`./configure.lineno: line 480: expr: command not found` the moment I want to compile ImageMagick.

Any thoughts, ideas?

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual not to have 'expr' in your toolbox of programs.

You should use your OS's packaging system to install image-magick. If you can't, then use your OS's packaging system to see that coreutils is installed.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I understand that. Could my OS's packaging system be jailkit? It's given on my ssh information "Chroot Shell : jailkit".
Thanks for your help so far

Comment: That is not the the packaging system. jailkit is restriction over your OS, and it might be why your mundane task running "expr" failed.